# Best approach to run different modes of clock in testbench

Tags: vhdl

I'm interested in running my current testcases with a different clock frequency without having to recreate new testcases with only the clock periods changed. Would using tcl script be better for something like this?

For example:

```
    testcase1 has 
    process
    begin
    wait for CLK_PERIOD / 2.0;
    CLK <= not CLK;
    wait forCLK_PERIOD / 2.0;
    NCLK <= not CLK;
    end process;
```

but i want to be able to run testcase1 with

```
    process
    begin
    wait for CLK_PERIOD1 / 2.0;
    CLK <= not CLK;
    wait forCLK_PERIOD1 / 2.0;
    NCLK <= not CLK;
    end process;
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. What methods are you currently using to manage and run the different test cases? Presumably you would like something that fits in well with that you already have.

Comment: Make CLK_PERIOD a signal?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the clock period as a generic to the testbench entity. Simulators can't handle any type of top-level generics so you can use a string generic and convert that to time. Below is an example for a VUnit testbench (I'm one of the authors so I avoid TCL if I can)

```
library vunit_lib;
context vunit_lib.vunit_context;

entity tb_test is
  generic (
    clk_period_as_string : string;
    runner_cfg : runner_cfg_t);
end tb_test;

architecture tb of tb_test is
  constant clk_period : time := time'value(clk_period_as_string);
begin
  test_runner : process
  begin
    test_runner_setup(runner, runner_cfg);

    info("Clock period set to: " & to_string(clk_period));

    test_runner_cleanup(runner);
  end process test_runner;
end;
```

A VUnit script can control this generic by creating several configurations of the testbench

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from vunit import VUnit

prj = VUnit.from_argv()

tb_lib = prj.add_library('tb_lib')
tb_lib.add_source_files(join(dirname(__file__), 'test', '*.vhd'))
tb = tb_lib.entity("tb_test")

generics = dict(clk_period_as_string="5 ns")
tb.add_config(name='clock period = 5 ns', generics=generics)

generics = dict(clk_period_as_string="10 ns")
tb.add_config(name='clock period = 10 ns', generics=generics)

prj.main()
```

The result will be

[image]